# Longitudinal data using functional principal components mixed effect models

Tags: panel-data, functional-data-analysis

I have collected speech perception performance in children during one-year followed-up (four time points). A battery of speech perception measures (i.e., five measures) were used at each test interval. I want to examine the effects of three variables on speech perception performance (i.e., gender, chronological age, maternal educational level and cognitive abilities). 
To reduce the number of speech perception tests we are dealing with，the original speech perception  scores will be reduced to a standardized speech perception score using the functional Principal Component Analysis.
Then, the mixed-effect models will be used to examine the effects of three variables on speech perception performance during one-year followed-up. 
Is it feasible? If not, is there any other methods?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated. I think you describe is feasible but I need some clarifications for a full answer. :) Here goes: 1. You fit an individual ME model to each FPC score right? 2. You do not interpreter each FPC individually do you? 3. Do you or don't you have multiple readings for a single individual at your recording times? (I think you do but maybe I misunderstood what you mean) In general the first two sentences of your post are the most ambiguous as the sound a bit too field-specific.